# Can you replace the words "such a" before the noun with the words "as such" after the noun?

Tags: word-order

For instance:
are these sentences equal in meaning and clarity?

> This isn't the time to delight oneself with such a luxury.
>
> This isn't the time to delight oneself with a fine luxury as such.

Comment: They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two usages of *such* are not equal in meaning in the given contexts.

> This isn't the time to delight oneself with such a fine luxury.

Here *such* causes the end to mean "so extreme a fine luxury."  ([such](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/such?&o=100074&s=t) - see definition 4)

> This isn't the time to delight oneself with a fine luxury as such.

Here *such* causes the end to mean "a fine luxury of this type." ([such](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/such?&o=100074&s=t) - see definition 1)

Comment: In the second example sentence, "as such" could also be interpreted to have a slightly different meaning of "[in that capacity](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+such)", so the sentence would carry the meaning "this isn't the time to delight oneself with a fine luxury for its own sake" (as opposed to partaking in said luxury, say, for work-related reasons).

Comment: @Dan Romik: Consider a more "natural" example of the basic *A is not a B as such* construction (which I think can *only* be used in the negative). *This comment isn't an answer **as such*** means something along the lines of *It wouldn't be strictly correct to describe this comment as an "answer"*, with the strong implication that it's *very similar* to an "answer". So I interpret OP's (exceptionally weird) text as meaning we should now enjoy something that's *almost, but not quite* a "fine luxury".

Comment: ...unless we postulate that *the time to delight oneself with a fine luxury* is a familiar concept to both conversants, in which case it's syntactically perfectly normal to me. The current situation is reminiscent of those times in some way, but it's not *actually* that kind of time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree the sentence is not well-constructed and is subject to several different interpretations, none of which makes too much sense. Btw as the link I posted above shows, _as such_ in this sense is not restricted to negative uses only (well, not as such anyway ;-)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So the first sentence is clear and the second is confusing to you? That is valuable info. to me.

Comment: @zehelvion: The key to this is that postpositive *as such* (at the *end* of a sentence) is almost always preceded by two "nouns" (call them A and B). The intent of the utterance (which invariably includes an explicit negation) is to deny that B actually *is* [a valid example of] A, whilst strongly implying/admitting that B is extremely similar to A in most respects. It's quite hard to imagine how exactly to apply that interpretation to your second sentence - especially because *structurally* A would normally correspond to ***This** [the current moment]*, but that's semantically tricky.